# How are continuous time MDPs handled?

Tags: markov-process, reinforcement-learning

In its most basic form, given a finite state space, transition probabilities, actions and a reward function, we can use value iteration or policy iteration to find the optimal policy. For continuous state space we can use discretization.

How are the cases with continuous time handled ? For eg. in the case of a continuous time random process like a Poisson process.

Comment: If you are accepting discretization for continuous state, then presumably you will accept discretization for continuous time - e.g. just set an arbitrary timestep at 100ms? That's the simplest possible answer. In practice you do not need discretization for continuous state or for continuous actions. However, I don't know whether there are more general continuous-time formulations for reinforcement learning - I suspect there may be, but they may come at a cost of less-well-developed theories and solutions.